# tkz-euclide problem with \newcolumntype

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm trying to run a latex file by Stefan Kottwitz, it calls tkz-euclide:

```
% Circles in and around a triangle
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 5/0/B, 1/4/C}
  \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
  \tkzGetPoint{M}
  \tkzGetLength{r}
  \tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
  \tkzGetPoint{N}
  \tkzGetLength{R}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--B](M)
  \tkzGetPoint{a}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](M)
  \tkzGetPoint{b}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--C](M)
  \tkzGetPoint{c}

  \tkzDrawCircle[R](M,\r pt)
  \tkzDrawCircle[R](N,\R pt)
  \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawLines[dotted](N,A N,B N,C)
  \tkzDrawLines[dashed](M,a M,b M,c)
  \tkzMarkRightAngles(M,a,B M,b,C M,c,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,a,b,c)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below left](A,M,a,c)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C,b)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](N)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I presented with and error.

[image]

I've dealt with this problem before, except this time I can't locate ./array.sty.

I apologise, that this isn't strictly a latex question.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was stupid, I didn't realize `array` would be loaded, indirectly, by `tkz-euclide`. Anyways, there is a file called `array.sty` in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: wow a pre-historic version of array.sty, where on earth did you find that 1990 dated version???

Comment: just delete the array.sty in that directory so latex finds the standard copy.

Comment: All great suggestions and comments, above and below. I

Answer (score 2):

The `array` package is a required part of the latex distribution so if you have latex at all you will have it.

However your log shows `(./array.sty`  which means that you are not using the standard package but a copy in the same directory as your document this is a museum piece: an early version from 1990!! that predates LaTeX2e and predates `\newcolumntype` being added to the package.  Simply delete the file in that directory and allow latex to find the standard one which will be in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
```

on your system although you don't need that information, just that it will be found in the standard input path.

Comment: All great suggestions and comments, one and all. I'm aware that it's an antique, the trouble is, where is it? I'm on a mac, I can't find that directory? In fact, why is that file on my system? I've got a few legacy items, how do I purge them? They are causing no end of trouble.

Comment: @LinoVari it appears to be in the same directory as your document, it is shown with full path `./array.sty` in the log you show.  Although technically it's in the working directory from wheer you ran latex if you started it as `pdflatex /some/path/to the input.tex` in either case it is in the directory where the pdf and log and things get generated

Comment: Thank you Mr. Carlisle, all fixed. One is never too old to learn, nor too old to be taught a lesson, much appreciated.